# UPDATE USING JOIN VS. WHERE EXISTS

Tags: sql, join, subquery, where-clause, exists

If JOIN and WHERE both describe inner joins in the following code, how come the WHERE clause in the subquery actually works as intended by selectively updating the desired rows, but the JOIN clause in the subquery updates all rows with the same value.

```
UPDATE #TEMP_ST
SET Absence = 1
where exists (SELECT * FROM sd.studentlist sl join
              #TEMP_ST st ON st.id = sl.studentid and
              st.fiscalyear = sl.fiscalyear and
              st.schoolid = sl.schoolid and
              sl.absence = 1)


UPDATE #TEMP_ST
SET Absence = 1
where exists (SELECT * FROM sd.studentlist sl
              where #TEMP_ST.id = sl.studentid and
              #TEMP_ST.fiscalyear = sl.fiscalyear and
              #TEMP_ST.schoolid = sl.schoolid and
              sl.absence = 1)
```

Comment: Because `join` doesn't limit the result set, and `where` does.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: This is a database I use in one of my work projects.  It's not Adventureworks or Northwind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the subquery without the join, `#TEMP_ST` refers to the table being updated. For each row in the table being updated, the subquery is evaluated using the values of the row being updated.

In the subquery with the join, you do not reference the table being updated. Regardless of the row being updated, the subquery returns the same result. All the rows are affected because the result is not empty.

Comment: Ok, I see, WHERE directly implies that you are updating the current row that meets the criteria, but JOIN doesn't imply that you are updating the current row and supplies only one value for update.